# Facebook graph query coordinates from posts feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, coordinates

How do I query all locations/coordinates from all posts in a certain *(open)* Facebook group?

I need them to map the users locations for some kind of research.

I tried searching the documentation and here but couldn't find it. Also tried in Facebook graph:

```
group_id/feed?fields=id,name,coordinates
```

but it only gives me a weird number, e.g.:

```
{ "data": [{  "id": "groupid_913215315438636"}
```

Comment: Please provide an example. If you are referring to user locations: These can't be retrieved from group posts.

Comment: I mean coordinates fo the facebook group posts, the moment they were posted.

For example: User_1 posted a picture on 25/09 in the group, but what are the coordinates of this post when he made it? This information must be there right?

If i then collect all coordinates of all posts, i can map them and create a heatmap of the posts.

Comment: There are no coordinates for group posts. If you are looking for coordinates for tagged places or similar there is no way to query them directly. You need to query all posts and see if any referred object within a message contains GEO coords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "weird" number is the group id. Since there is no coordinates field for the feed object you do not find it in the docs.

Messages posted to a group feed do not include any GEO data, only objects tagged within a message (like a place or a page) can have GEO data.

Besides that the user object also does not include GEO data, but only a location id, but to query that you need the user's permission. So it's not possible to get the user's location data from a Facebook group feed that way.

Comment: Thanks, then we'll manually have to find out locations indeed (users post the street names, gives a rough estimate).. 

but the first number of "id" is the group_id, so what's the second number? Userid i suppose? When i do the query below:


GET&path=234419406651567%2Ffeed%3Ffields(latitude%2Clongitude)&version=v2.4

Comment: The 2nd number is the ID identifying the post within the group (groupip_postid)